# How do I create a horizontal line with text in the middle?

Tags: objective-c

I'm **very** new to Objective C but I'm looking at the source code of an existing app so there's a lot here to sift through.

I'm trying to create something like this:

-------------- or --------------

...only with a solid horizontal line instead of the dashes.

I have the "or" text defined as this:

```
    _orLabel = ^{
    UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] init];

    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    label.font = [UIFont mainFontWithSize:[UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleSubheadline].pointSize];
    label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    label.text = NSLocalizedString(@"or", nil);

    [view addSubview:label];

    return label;
}();
```

That's working great to get "or" to show up but I have no idea how to get the horizontal lines on either side.

Answer (score 1):

I would subclass UILabel and override [`drawTextInRect:`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uilabel/1620527-drawtextinrect?language=objc). The easiest way is to call `super` so that the text gets drawn. Now you are still in a graphics context (CGContext) so you can use ordinary Quartz drawing commands to draw your horizontal lines.

Comment: See my book for more about drawing commands: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch15.html#_paths_and_drawing

Comment: Also here's an actual example of overriding `drawTextInRect:`; the goal is different (namely, to put a box around the label) but the idea is exactly the same: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch10.html#_subclassing Scroll down to the paragraph that starts "Here’s an example from one of my own apps, in which I subclass UILabel".

Comment: Of course you could go even further and just draw an image yourself, showing a line, the word "or", and a line, and display it as a UIImage or as a view's self-drawing. You hardly need a UILabel for something as simple as this.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is to make use of certain Unicode characters that will give you a solid line.

```
label.text = @"───────── or ─────────";
```

That text is using a series of "BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT HORIZONTAL" characters (U+2500).

Comment: This should work in some cases but is sort of hacky — if you've got specific width restrictions, the characters are not arbitrarily truncatable, and it might be difficult to make sure the lines are the same length in a proportional font otherwise... Also not all fonts have box drawing characters.

Answer (score 0):

I would use IB to add a view on each side of the label.  Make the views have a height of 1 or 2 with a black background, and use autolayout to make them size appropriately for the label and screen situation:

1. Make view #1 anchored to the left edge of the screen and the right side of the label.
2. Make view #2 anchored to the right edge of the screen and the left side of the label.
3. Make the 2 views and the label have the same vertical center.